# AWS Cognito Login and Angular 2 routing

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, angular2-routing, angular2-services, amazon-cognito

I'm not able to navigate to next page on success of AWS Cognito Login authentication from my angular 2 web app. Login is successful and I can see the token in console, but when I navigate on success of authentication I get below mentioned error. What is the mistake?

It throws me this error:

```
 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

The code is as follows:

**Component**

```
authenticateUser(loginCredentials:any){

       var authenticationData = {
            Username : loginCredentials.username,
            Password : loginCredentials.password
        };
        //console.log("authenticationData..",authenticationData);
        var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
        console.log("authenticationDetails..",authenticationDetails);
        var poolData = {
            UserPoolId : "cognito user pool id ", // Your user pool id here
            ClientId : "cognito user pool client id" // Your client id here
        };
        //console.log("poolData..",poolData);
        var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
        console.log("userPool..",userPool);
        var userData = {
            Username : loginCredentials.username,
            Pool : userPool
        };
        //console.log("userData..",userData);
        var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
        console.log("cognitoUser..",cognitoUser);

        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {
                console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
                console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);

                if(result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken() != null){

                    this.router.navigate(['nextPage']);

                }


            },

            onFailure: function(err) {
                console.log('error : ' + err);
                alert(err);
            },


        })

   }
```

Comment: Probably `this` is lost because you call router function inside a cognito callback. Try to save `this` into a variable (say, `self`) before this function and call it like `self.router...`.

Comment: @wostex how do I do that? Can you show me an example?

Comment: Before `cognitoUser.authenticateUser` define `var self = this;` and instead of `this.router.navigate` use `self.router.navigate`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to turn it into a promise instead using callbacks and handle your logic inside "then and catch".
This would allow you to better control your code and re-use it else where.
I have converted your code to a promise and added one of my code that used be callback before and I converted to a promise for you to compare.
A lot of engineers use promises or observables instead callbacks nightmare.

BELOW, YOUR CODE USING PROMISES.

```js
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails).promise().then(result => {
  console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
  console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
  if (result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken() !== null) {
    this.router.navigate(['nextPage']);
  }
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('error : ' + err);
  alert(err);
})
```

BELOW, MY CODE USING CALLBACKS AND THEN USING PROMISES.

```js
confirmSMSLogin(data: string) {
  AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxx-xxxx.etc',
  });

  const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
  const params = {
    ChallengeName: 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE',
    ClientId: 'asdf1234...etc',
    ChallengeResponses: {
      USERNAME: this.userModelService.LoginUserModelService[0].username,
      ANSWER: data
    },
    Session: this.userModelService.LoginUserModelService[0].session
  };


  // DISABLED THIS FUNCTION WITH CALLBACKS WHICH LIMITED THE CONTROL OVER THE FUNCTION.
  // cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.respondToAuthChallenge(params, function(err, data) {
  //   if (err) {
  //     console.log(err, err.stack);
  //   } else { // successful response
  //     console.log('Successful Authentication');
  //     AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  //       IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:asdf1234..etc',
  //       Logins: {'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-asdf..etc':
  //         data['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']}
  //     });
  //   }
  // })

  // Changed aws function callbacks to promise to better control of the flow.
  return cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.respondToAuthChallenge(params).promise().then((data) => {
    console.log('Success to Log in')
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:asdf1234...etc',
      Logins: {
        'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1asdf..etc': data['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']
      }
    });
    this.userModelService.UserSignedInModelService.push(this.jwtHelper1.decodeToken(data.AuthenticationResult.IdToken))
    this.router.navigate([''])
  }).catch((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('has an error', err)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I can't find the IdentityPoolId in the aws console?

Comment: You are talking about console panel? if that, you can find more info here
[link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html)
and here Cognito Pool
[link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-console.html)